# How to to center TextView to be always in center of Layout?

Tags: android

I need to create navigation bar (which I include in many activities.xml) with background which has TextView at center with titlw and back button (sometimes Back button is visible sometimes is not). How to to center TextView to be always in center of Layout ? At the moment when Back is visible TextView is moved slightly to right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/header_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_previous_arrow"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A RelativeLayout will suit your needs better:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/header_background" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_previous_arrow"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Title" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Attribute `layout_centerInParent` will only work if the width and height are set to `wrap_content`. Alternatively, you can set the height and width to `fill_parent` and set the TextView's `android:gravity="center"`.

Why your original layout was not working:

A LinearLayout does not allow overlapping of views. So, even though you set the TextView's height and width to fill_parent, it actually only fills up the space leftover after placing the back button. So, when the button is not visible, TextView is centered. When the button is visible, TextView is centered in the remainder of space: thus shifted a bit to the right.

Edit: Correction made (replaced `android:layout_alignLeft="true"` with `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`)

Comment: @kcoppock I meant one thing and typed another. Thanks for spotting the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="@style/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Title" />
```